# Adding an Org to HLF Sample Network - but with tweaks?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are making the transition from HL Composer to native Fabric and are trying to adjust a working demo model we have been developing to your sample network discussion here: 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/network/network.html

Our network rules differ **only slightly** but can someone please confirm or correct our approach? Differences are noted below:

Five organizations, R1, R2, R3, R4 and R5 have jointly decided, and written into an agreement, that they will set up and exploit a HL Fabric network, our demo network N.

Difference — R4 is the corporate parent of R1 and has business oversight over everything R1 does — but does not involve itself in day-to-day operations. This is important as it wants to view/review everything but does not take actions itself.

Background — R1 loans, for a fee, certain assets to both R2 and R3. It may loan the same asset to both but the terms of the loan transaction are private between R1/R2 and R1/R3. Because R2 and R3 are charitable, when certain events occur, R2 and R3 also pay a fee to R5. R5 conducts no other transactions across the network except to receive and acknowledge receipt of this charity.

**Edit for clarity: Unlike the sample HLF network, our demo network has R1 and R3 on C2 -- not R2 & R3.**

R4 has been assigned to be the network initiator (admin) – it has been given the power to set up the initial version of the network. R4 has no intention to perform business transactions on the network.

**Difference — however we want R4 to have complete visibility into all transactions, transfer of assets, etc. IOW we want to give R4 a “gods-eye view” of the demo network N. Everything including channel activity.**

**Is this possible?**

R1 and R2 have a need for a private communications within the overall network. R1 and R3 have the same need.

**Difference — R5 will have rights to view certain transactions on each of C1 and C2 — to acknowledge correct payments is being made from R2 and R3 and to accept those payments. R5 may also submit a report of transactions back to R1 and R4.**

Is this possible? **IOW can we join R5 to C1 and to C2 with certain rights? C1 would grant R5 rights to review payment proposals, accept them and report on them. C2 would do the same. Privacy would be maintained within C1, same for C2. IOW R2 and R3 would not have visibility into each others activity.**

All other aspects of your sample network discussion — ordering service, number of channels, etc., we want to remain the same — using your current logic.

In addition to your other details, each of the five organizations has a preferred Certificate Authority se we will be adding a CA for R5.

**We do not believe R5 will need a separate peer or ordering service but this may be incorrect -- can someone please confirm or correct?**

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked a lot of questions, I will try to answer as many as I can in no particular order. I think some of the confusion arises from the fact that there is no equivalent of `permissions.acl` in this system.

> Difference — R4 is the corporate parent of R1 and has business oversight over everything R1 does — but does not involve itself in day-to-day operations. This is important as it wants to view/review everything but does not take actions itself.

If you want each org to have their own CA, then this point does not matter. R4 will have its own peer nodes and CA. If you are willing to treat R4 and R1 as one entity, you can reduce your system to 4 organizations.

> R4 has been assigned to be the network initiator (admin) – it has been given the power to set up the initial version of the network.

Afaik there is no such thing as network initiator. In Hyperledger Composer, what we called the PeerAdmin was the admin for a single organization. For a network to be setup, each organization has their own Admin who will connect the peers to channels and install required chaincode. It has to be a joint effort.

> R4 has no intention to perform business transactions on the network.

Great, then R4 doesn't need to make any API calls. Nothing much to do here.

> We want to give R4 a “gods-eye view” of the demo network

Only possible if peer nodes under R4 have joined all the channels. They automatically get read access and can perform rich queries.

> R5 will have rights to view certain transactions on each of C1 and C2

Sounds like R5 is a regulator/ overseer of sorts. For this to work, they need to join both channels which you have figured out, which means either the guys at R5 access the nodes that R4 has setup, or have a node of their own. IRL scenario, an overseer should have independent peer node for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems all good for now but as the number of orgs would grow maintaining seperate channels between set of orgs would become a big nightmare plus it would also affect the performance.

Why not try using **private data collection**  instead of adding new channels everytime you want privacy between two parties.In this way only the intented parties in the network would be able to view the transaction data.

R5 would need a peer.

Comment: Thanks @Risabh-Sharma for this. Orgs of type R2/R3 may grow but their number in our universe will be limited -- in the real world, if there were 10 total, this would be significant. Why would R5 need a peer? Also, if R5 does not join to a channel, how would one depict your suggested private data collection within the network diagram? Apologies if these are basic questions. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Every org would  need a peer/peers to interact with the network.so R5 would require a peer,and the access control can be done by putting access rights in the configtx.yaml file.